# extract words from list after specific character

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have two lists:

```
list_1 = ['08667\nST 403', '08667\nST 403', '08667\nST 403']
list_2 = ['12233\nFION', '12233\nFION', '12233\nFION', '12233\nFION', '31147\nARAB\nP1454']
```

I want to be able to extract the names after the '\n' keyword.

I am using this code:

```
def parse_string(string):
    string = string.rsplit('\n', 1)[1]
    return string

list_1 = ['08667\nST 403', '08667\nST 403', '08667\nST 403']
list_2 = ['12233\nFION', '12233\nFION', '12233\nFION', '12233\nFION', '31147\nARAB\nP1454']


new_list_1 = []
new_list_2 = []

for i in range(len(list_1)):
    new_list_1.append(parse_string(list_1[i]))

for i in range(len(list_2)):
    new_list_2.append(parse_string(list_2[i]))
```

For the `list_1`, it works fine:

```
new_list_1
['ST 403', 'ST 403', 'ST 403']
```

but for the `list_2`:

```
new_list_2
['FION', 'FION', 'FION', 'FION', 'P1454']
```

So, the last element is `P1454` instead of `ARAB`.

How can I automate this to work for all cases?

Comment: But `P1454` is *also* one of the "names after the '\n' keyword".  If you only want *certain* names, how is the program to decide?

Comment: Do you want just `ARAB` and not `P1454` ?

Comment: just `string = string.split('\n')[1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use list comprehension. It will work for both the lists.

```
list_1 = ['08667\nST 403', '08667\nST 403', '08667\nST 403']
list_2 = ['12233\nFION', '12233\nFION', '12233\nFION', '12233\nFION', '31147\nARAB\nP1454']


[x.split('\n')[1] for x in list_1]
#['ST 403', 'ST 403', 'ST 403']

[x.split('\n')[1] for x in list_2]
#['FION', 'FION', 'FION', 'FION', 'ARAB']
```

---

Now if you want `P1454` instead of `ARAB` you can do:

```
[x.split('\n')[2] if len(x.split('\n'))>2  else x.split('\n')[1] for x in list_2]

#['FION', 'FION', 'FION', 'FION', 'P1454']
```

This will work for `list_1` as well:

```
[x.split('\n')[2] if len(x.split('\n'))>2  else x.split('\n')[1] for x in list_1]

#['ST 403', 'ST 403', 'ST 403']
```

---

**Universal Solution for both lists both values:**

```
[x.split('\n')[1:] for x in list_2]
#[['ST 403'], ['ST 403'], ['ST 403']]

[x.split('\n')[1:] for x in list_2]
#[['FION'], ['FION'], ['FION'], ['FION'], ['ARAB', 'P1454']]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def f(l_st):
    result = []
    for st in l_st:
        lst = re.findall(r'\n([A-Z]+\s*[A-Z0-9]*)', st)
        if "\n" in lst[0]:
            x, y = re.split(r'\n', "".join(lst[0]))
            result.append(x)
            result.append(y)
        else:
            result.append(lst[0])
    return result

print(f(list_1))
['ST 403', 'ST 403', 'ST 403']
print(f(list_2))
['FION', 'FION', 'FION', 'FION', 'ARAB', 'P1454']
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution, using `re`:

```py
import re

list_1 = ["08667\nST 403", "08667\nST 403", "08667\nST 403"]
list_2 = [
    "12233\nFION",
    "12233\nFION",
    "12233\nFION",
    "12233\nFION",
    "31147\nARAB\nP1454",
]

new_list_1 = [re.search(r"(?<=\n).*", s).group(0) for s in list_1]
new_list_2 = [re.search(r"(?<=\n).*", s).group(0) for s in list_2]

print(f"{new_list_1=}")
print(f"{new_list_2=}")
```

Prints:

```
new_list_1=['ST 403', 'ST 403', 'ST 403']
new_list_2=['FION', 'FION', 'FION', 'FION', 'ARAB']
```